# Istio EnvoyFilter Lua HTTP Filter - How to get request URI from request_handle?

Tags: lua, istio, envoyproxy, istio-sidecar

I know that 2 Lua functions are called in a filter when a call is made :

```
function envoy_on_request(request_handle)
end

function envoy_on_response(response_handle)
end
```

How can I retrieve the **Request URI Path/query params** from the request_handle?

EDIT:
I found a couple of headers called ":path" and "x-original-url" but which is the source of truth?

Answer (score 1):

You have access to all the headers in a request/response using `handle:headers()`.

```
function envoy_on_request(request_handle)
  -- Log information about the request
  request_handle:logInfo("URL: "..request_handle:headers():get(":x-original-url"))
  request_handle:logInfo("Path: "..request_handle:headers():get(":path"))
end

function envoy_on_response(response_handle)
  -- Log response status code
  response_handle:logInfo("Status: "..response_handle:headers():get(":status"))
end
```

Comment: Where are these headers added? Can I expect these headers to be there always ?